# Initializing all textboxes with a for loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops, textbox, controls

I have an Initialization for a  userform. It works fine when I initialize using the commented out part of the code, but when I use the code as shown below, I get a runtime error 91.

I need a way to loop through or select all textboxes to give them default value, color and etc...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim i As Long
Dim ctl As Control
For i = 1 To 4
    ctl = "TextBox" & i
    ctl.Value = ""
Next i
'TextBox1.Value = ""
'TextBox2.Value = ""
'TextBox3.Value = ""
'TextBox4.Value = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: `Controls("TextBox" & i) = ""` would be the way to do it in a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to refer to a `TextBox` of the form, you need `Controls("TextboxN)`. If you want to loop, it is like this - `Me.Controls("Textbox" & i)`, in case that you have not deleted any textboxes and they are following the default order
Thus, this is a possibility:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim ctl As Control
    For i = 1 To 4
        Me.Controls("Textbox" & i) = i
        Me.Controls("Textbox" & i).BackColor = vbGreen
    Next i

    Debug.Print Me.TextBox3.Value

End Sub
```

With this screenshot, showing each TextBox getting a value of 1,2,3 or 4 and a green color:

[image]

Or even this, if you want to make the outlook of the controls a bit different:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim i       As Long
    Dim ctl     As Control

    For i = 1 To 4
        With Me.Controls("Textbox" & i)
            .Value = i
            If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
                .BackColor = vbBlue
                .ForeColor = vbWhite
            Else
                .BackColor = vbGreen
                .BackColor = vbRed
            End If
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

If you are naming the textboxes, following your own programming logic, then looping through the collection of controls and checking the `TypeName` of the control is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

make a procedure in normal module:

```
Sub LoopTxBox()
    Dim tb As MSForms.Control

    For Each tb In UserForm1.Controls
        If TypeName(tb) = "TextBox" Then   'capitalisation matters
            '...
        End If
    Next tb

End Sub
```

and call it in UserForm_Initialize().